# Does Windows (or NTFS) support placeholder files with fake sizes?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs

Every time I start Photoshop, it immediately creates a 2GB temporary file on the hard drive where the cache is located. It's a platter drive, and I don't hear any of the hard-drive noises that would normally be associated with writing 2GB of data. Is it possible to create an empty placeholder file with a "fake" size to reserve space in case it actually needs to cache some data later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different ways this can be accomplished on an NTFS volume.

The [`SetEndOfFile` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx), on NTFS file systems, reserves the disk space for the file but does not fill that space with anything. There might be a little disk activity here from updating the NTFS bookkeeping. When a program does anything to a file past the last byte that has previously been written, NTFS scribbles over the run between the last written (last "valid") byte and the requested byte (to avoid [security problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544.aspx)) and updates the valid data pointer.

Then there are [sparse files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa365564.aspx). Unlike normal files extended with `SetEndOfFile`, NTFS keeps track of which sectors have actual data in them rather than just which byte is the last one with valid data. Long runs of zeroes where nothing has been written are not stored on the physical disk.

You can check whether a file is sparse with `fsutil sparse queryflag` followed by the path to the file. If it's not sparse, the program is using the first approach.

Further reading: [Why does my single-byte write take forever?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110922-00/?p=9573)

Comment: My guess is that Photoshop doesn't use sparse files, since they can suddenly return "disk full" errors in the middle of something important, while `SetEndOfFile`-extended files commit the physical space ahead of time.

Comment: a bit late to the party, but there is not really a distinction between the two types. A NTFS file record has a length (Allocated Size/Reserved Size), and it has information about which sectors are covered (in the Run List). Empty sectors are don’t have a location, but a length, so they are jumped over. If a file is created, and SetEndOfFile is called at 1GB, then only the size if 1GB is noted down. When now a byte is written, the entire cluster at 1GB is zeroed, the byte is inserted, and a run list with 1GB free and 1 sector used after that 1GB is written to the record.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is called "sparse file".

NTFS and ReFS support it, but FAT32 and ExFAT not.

A program can explicitly tell the OS which byte ranges of a file should have space on the disk (per default, it's everything). The other, unallocated parts are treated like the contain just a lot of bytes with value 0 if read by the program.

In the file properties dialog, you'll see a "normal" file size, that's the "fake" one, and a size how much is used on the disk, that's the allocated part (plus some byte to get full HDD blocks).

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: It is my understanding that NTFS is responsible for allocating real space to sparse files; applications just cause sections to be allocated by writing to them. See my answer for more information.

Comment: @BenN Writing implies allocating, yes. Still, manual allocation/deallocation of byte ranges is possible.

Comment: Ah, I think we're looking for the [`FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364597(v=vs.85).aspx) code, which sets a region to zero and can cause NTFS to deallocate it.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in tool [fsutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil) can quickly create a non-sparse file full of zeroes, with `fsutil file createNew <filename> <bytes>`.  It will take up space on the disk, but the zero blocks won't need to be written to (assuming you're using NTFS or similar).

Here's an example of creating a 10GB file.  The hard disk free space will drop by 10GB, but the action should happen very quickly.

```
C:\>fsutil file createNew dummy 10737418240
File C:\dummy is created

C:\>fsutil sparse queryFlag dummy
This file is NOT set as sparse
```